# Encontrar el indexOf entre dos array en JavaScript con un forEach

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como hallar el `indexOf` en `JS` entre dos `array`, un `array` contiene los valores dados y el otro `array` los valores que quiero conocer su `indexOf`

```js
var act = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001879,3508477478,10001881];
var actselect = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001881];
var posicion = act.indexOf(actselect); //en vez de un numero necesito insertar un array que lo haga por cada valor
console.log(posicion); //la respuesta debería se (0,1,5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya obtuvo una respuesta con `map`, y como su pregunta dice `forEach` , daré un ejemplo de como sería con `forEach` , tomando una validación adicional para saber si existe o no el elemento porque no si no se estaría llenando el `array` con `-1`  que es el valor de retorno de `indexOf` cuando no existe el elemento.

```js
var act = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001879,3508477478,10001881];
var actselect = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001881];
var posiciones = []; // array posiciones
actselect.forEach(function(el){
 // Sí el indexOf retorna diferente a -1 es porque lo encontró y 
 // lo aañade al array de posiciones
 if((index = act.indexOf(el)) !==-1) 
  posiciones.push(index);
});

console.log(posiciones);
```

**Edit**

Si desea obtener los elementos a partir de un `array` dado puede emplear `map` o `filter` para retornar el `array` según sea los  indices especificados en `actselect`

```js
var act = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001879,10001881]; 
var actselect = [0,1,3]; 
var posicion = actselect.map(function(el){
 return act[el];
});
console.log(posicion);
```

Comment: Hola Joel muchas gracias, te quiero preguntar ahora, si tengo en el array actselect los indices ej[0,2,3] como hago para imprimir esos 3 valores del array act?? te agrdezco tu respuesta asta ahora estoy entrando en el mundo de la programacion

Comment: Me explico tengo el siguiente codigo:
`var act = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001879,10001881];
var actselect = 1;
var posicion = act[actselect]
console.log(posicion); //10001755`

ahora bien en necesito colocar un array y no un valor dinamico ejemplo:
var actselet = [0,1,3];

Comment: @RafaelPereira según lo que entendí de su pregunta. actualicé mi respuesta tomando está consideración. Revise y si no queda claro comenta.

Comment: Joel te envio un link en donde tengo el codigo y la explicacion de lo que quiero [link](https://jsbin.com/yanoserebu/edit?js,console)

Comment: @RafaelPereira eso hace mi segundo ejemplo en mi respuesta.  lo probó ? mi ejemplo retorna un `array` con los valores `10002197,10001755,10001879`  [link del ejemplo en jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jusofupafe/edit?js,console)

Comment: De acuerdo ya lo vi, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método `map` del objeto `Array` que permite tratar uno por uno los elementos de un array y devuelve un array con los resultados:

```js
var act = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001879,3508477478,10001881];
var actselect = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001881];

var posiciones = actselect.map((e) => act.indexOf(e)); 

console.log(posiciones);
```

Comment: Gracias me funcionó